# Вывод содержимого json файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Есть json файл типа:

```
{
    "b1": [
        "2222",
        "1111"
    ],
    "b2": [
        "33333"
    ]
}
```

И есть 2 кнопки:

```
<button class='b1'>button1</button>  
<button class='b2'>button2</button>
```

Нужно чтобы по нажатию на одну из этих кнопок появлялась только нужная часть json файла

```
$(".button").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("json/persons.json", function(result, iden){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $("#person").append(field);
            });
        });
    });
```

Этот скрипт открывает весь файл, а писать на каждую кнопку один и тот же код, который отличается лишь `result.b1`, `result.b2` и `result.bN` как то не хочется. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного проработал предыдущие ответы, так как считаю, что нет необходимости при каждом клике подгружать повторно файл. Плюс к этому заменил метод `.append()` на `.html()`, получается своеобразный переключатель контента из подгруженного файла.

```
var persons;
var btnSwitch = "button[class*='b']";

$(function() {
    $.getJSON("json/persons.json", function(result) {
        persons = result;
    })
})

$(btnSwitch).click(function () {
    $("#person").html(persons[this.className] || '')
});
```

Comment: @АзиретКадыкеев а это бабушка на двое сказала, бог его знает, может данные то меняются со временем?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".button").click(function () {
  var $button = $(this);
  $.getJSON("json/persons.json", function(result, iden) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      if ($button.hasClass(i)) {
        // field here is array, iterate over it if needed
        $("#person").append(field);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = {
    "b1": [
        "2222",
        "1111"
    ],
    "b2": [
        "33333"
    ]
}

$("button").click(function () {
    let c = this.className
    //$.getJSON("json/persons.json", function(result, iden){
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            $("#person").append(result[c].join(''));
        });
    //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='b1'>button1</button>  
<button class='b2'>button2</button>
<div id="person"><div>
```